# Create issue of type Epic with Jira C# SDK

Tags: c#, jira

I'm using the Jira C# SDK 2.4.0

I need to create a new Epic before creating my issues, so I can assign the Epic Link to them.

```
Jira jiraConnection = new Jira(url, user, password);
Issue issue = jiraConnection.CreateIssue(projectKey);
issue.Type = "Epic";
issue.Summary = "My first epic";
issue.SaveChanges();
```

This gives me the following error, telling me the "Epic Name" is required.

```
com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException: {customfield_10008=Epic Name is required.} : []
```

This makes sense as in Jira it's a required field. I then added the following line

```
issue["customfield_10008"] = "EpicTest"; //epic name field
```

And I get the following error

```
Could not find custom field with name 'customfield_10008' on the JIRA server. Make sure this field is available when editing this issue. For more information see JRA-6857
```

There doesn't seem to be a "Epic Name" property in the Issue object either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, was easy after all

```
issue.CustomFields.Add("Epic Name", "test");
```